# Typing ~ on macbook pro keyboard

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

I have a macbook pro 2015, and I've got the UK keyboard layout. I have trouble typing the standard ~ character as I've only got §/±. Does anyone know any workarounds?

Comment: What character do You have on the left side from the letter `Z` ?

Comment: Oh well that was very unintuitive by me. Thanks a lot Mateusz, that character seems to input ` and ~. Much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~` on a UK keyboard is located on the left side of the <kbd>Z</kbd> key. To get it, you have to press it with <kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd>.

[image: Keyboard with tilde key marked.]